# PHP: Filling out form in PDF using FPDM: unnamed text annotations

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to fill out a pdf form using FPDM and get this error message:

> FPDF-Merge Error: Annot Widget (obj id=257) is a text annotation without
>   a name, this cannot be.

I did some research on the internet, tried to fix the problem using pdftk on the document "pdftk file1.pdf output file2.pdf" (as the documentation on [fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) suggests) and took a look into the source code of PDFM. To be honest, I don't quite understand the error message. To me it sounds like an unnamed tooltip that shouldn't bother me for filling out some form elements. That's why I tried to modify FPDM to ignore these unnamed annotations. I also opened and saved the document using Adobe Acrobat (just in case the original pdf file might be corrupt). All these things didn't work out and I have no clue how I could fix it.

Any suggestions are welcome. I also uploaded the [PDF-file](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8878846/vmg_rate_1.pdf.html).

Answer (score 0):

A text annotation is also known as "comment" in general Acrobat speak. Text annotations are (if I remember correctly) free text, added using the Text comment tool.

I do not know if the original document does have such an object, or if it is some kind of artefact. What happens when you do a Save as… in Acrobat (preferably after deactivating the "save as optimizes for fast web view" option in the preferences). This may flush such stray objects.

Another possibility would be to start with a virgin original (meaning that there are no fields in the document), and then copy/paste the fields from your prepared document. If that annotation was an artefact, you should have gotten rid of it by now.

If nothing helps, try to locate the ob id 257 and show it here (you may then have to show additional objects, but I don't know yet if it is necessary.